# Double Domain In Reports

Tags: google-analytics

I have configured Advance Filter to track the sub-domains record as follow:

Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced

Field A: Hostname

Extract A: (.*)

Field B: Request URI

Extract B: (.*)

Output To: Request URI

Constructor: $A1$B1

After that, I am able to see sub-domains record and View Full Page URL In Reports. But when I check reports e.g. Acquisition >> Social >> Landing Pages a double domain name name is displayed in the report:

For example :
In landing page list following URL given :

www.b78.is/athlete/sarah-mcnair/

But the report appears as:

www.b78.iswww.b78.is/athlete/sarah-mcnair/

How Can I remove double domains?